# Is there a way to map numerical values to a range of numbers in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, range, mapping

I'm trying to map a range of values to variables as shown below. The function containers.Map doesn't seem to help. I would like to know if there is any inbuilt function to do.

For example :  Range is between 5.27 to 5.32 and there are many sub ranges

```
R1 = 5.27 to 5.279, 
R2 = 5.28 to 5.289, 
R3 = 5.29 to 5.299,
R4 = 5.30 to 5.309,
R5 = 5.31 to 5.319 & 
R6 = 5.32 to 5.329.
```

I would like to assign values for each of these ranges such as

```
R1 = 150                R2 = 160           R3 = 170
R4 = 180                R5 = 190           R6 = 200.
```

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your ranges are all uniform, you can simply apply a linear transform that will help you get to your desired range.

Note that the minimum of your values is 5.27, the maximum is 5.33 and the range of each bin is 0.01.  Therefore, take a candidate value subtract by 5.27, divide by 0.01 so that you can determine which bin it maps to (i.e. goes from 0 to 5) by taking the `floor`.

You also know that your minimum value in the new range is 150 with steps of 10 to go to the next bin. Therefore, simply take your new step size, multiply by this bin value and add with 150.  Supposing your old values are stored in `query`, you would thus do:

```
norm_val = floor((query - 5.27) / 0.01);
new_val = 150 + 10 * norm_val;
```

An example showing this working.  Suppose we have the following query:

```
>> query = [5.285 5.298 5.312]

query =

    5.2850    5.2980    5.3120
```

Running through the code we get:

```
>> new_val

new_val =

   160   170   190
```

We can see that the value 5.285 maps to the second bin, which is 160.  The value of 5.298 maps to the third bin, which is 170.  Finally, the value of 5.312 maps to the fifth bin, which is 190.

Answer (score 1):

Use `discretize` to bin the data.

Assuming `x` contains the data, set up the edges of the bins and the values to be assigned. The `discretize` function will assign bin numbers to each value. Use the bin numbers as indexes into the R values vector.

```
Rvals = [150:10:200];
edges = [5.27:.01:5.33];
bins = discretize(x, edges);
binnedData = Rvals(bins);
```